# versioning serialization in c# when using iserializable interface

Tags: c#, serialization

I have a base class FDObjectBase which inherits from ContentControl, ISerializable, INotifyPropertyChanged. Now this class gets de-serialized  using the below code logic

```
public FDObjectBase(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : this()
{
   Left = (double)info.GetValue("Left", typeof(double));
    Top = (double)info.GetValue("Top", typeof(double));
    Height = (double)info.GetValue("Height", typeof(double));
    Width = (double)info.GetValue("Width", typeof(double));
    DesignObjectID = (int)info.GetValue("DesignObjectID", typeof(int));
    ShapeType = (int)info.GetValue("ShapeType", typeof(int));
    Angle = (double)info.GetValue("Angle", typeof(double));
    try
    {
        ObjectType = (ObjectType)info.GetValue("ObjectType", typeof(ObjectType));
        //this.ToolTip = ObjectType.ToString();
    }
    catch { }

    OnDeserialized(new EventArgs());
    //DataObject = (DesignData)info.GetValue("DataObject", typeof(DesignData));
    //this.ToolTip = DataObject.Name + " (" + DataObject.ObjectType.ToString().ToLower() + ")";    

}
```

This works fine in the application however the issue is that i want the de-serialization process to be backward compatible since as per the requirement changes to the this class must not break the de-serialized data which is stored in the database.
The solution which i found for this is to add the  [OptionalField] attribute to all the new fields which are added to this class however this has not worked out for me. I am still getting the same exception when i add a new field this class (After adding the new field the deserialization does not happen and the below exception is thrown)

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException was caught
  Message=Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._SerializationInvoke(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, SignatureStruct& declaringTypeSig, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.CompleteISerializableObject(Object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.FixupSpecialObject(ObjectHolder holder)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.DoFixups()
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream)
       at .SeatManagement.Client.Helpers.Generics.Deserialize[T](String data) in Generics.cs:line 117
  InnerException: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException
       Message=Member 'Test' was not found.
       Source=mscorlib
```

So i am looking for any suggestions which are in the direction of versioning serialization c# when using iserializable interface so that it does not break even when we add new fields to the class. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have found a solution to this .. however it does not use the out of the box features which are provided by  System.Runtime.Serialization.
I have added a property version on my base class

```
private static int VERSION_NUMBER = 1;
```

which gets serialized along with the other design properties as below.

```
public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
    info.AddValue("Version", VERSION_NUMBER);
    //First Version properties
    info.AddValue("Left", Left);
    info.AddValue("Top", Top);
    info.AddValue("Height", Height);
    info.AddValue("Width", Width);
    info.AddValue("DesignObjectID", DesignObjectID);
    info.AddValue("ShapeType", ShapeType);
    info.AddValue("ObjectType", ObjectType.GetIntValue());
    info.AddValue("Angle", Angle);
    //Second Version Properties
}
```

Now when i deserialize the string i check the version which is stored in the deserialized string

```
public FDObjectBase(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : this()
{
    int version = Generics.GetSerializedValue<int>(info, "Version");

    if (version >= 1)
    {
        Left = (double)info.GetValue("Left", typeof(double));
        Top = (double)info.GetValue("Top", typeof(double));
        Height = (double)info.GetValue("Height", typeof(double));
        Width = (double)info.GetValue("Width", typeof(double));
        DesignObjectID = (int)info.GetValue("DesignObjectID", typeof(int));
        ShapeType = (int)info.GetValue("ShapeType", typeof(int));
        Angle = (double)info.GetValue("Angle", typeof(double));
        ObjectType = ((int)info.GetValue("ObjectType", typeof(int))).GetEnumValue<ObjectType>();
    }
    if (version >= 2)
    {
        //Add newly added properties for this version
    }
    else { 
        //Add default values for new properties for this version
    }

    OnDeserialized(new EventArgs());

}
```

So now when i add a new property which was not deserialized earlier i just increment the version and add the new properties under the second if statement. This way the information which is stored in the DB is always backward compatible.
It might not be the best solution but it works perfectly for me.

Comment: Tipp: You can use the class `System.Version` instead of an `int`.